# Opus audio codec on ARM cortex m4 microcontroller (Teensy 3.1) - GNU Auto tools

Tags: autotools, arduino-ide, opus, audio-comparison, teensy

I'm trying to turn the Teensy 3.1 microcontroller into a compressed audio recorder, so I want to compress a buffer of raw audio data.
After a research I found [Opus Codec](http://www.opus-codec.org/), an open source audio codec project that got ARM cortex M4 optimization, can work in floating point mode (and more).

I guess that my problem is with the GNU Auto tools
how to build opus codec in a way that I will be able to use it on the microcontroller?

Can work in Arduino IDE or any other IDE around 
I'm writing this question after weeks of attempts to use the Opus Codec

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If autotools is causing problems, try the Makefile.unix. You'll most likely want to enable fixed-point.